# When Joining a Domain, How to Remove Pre-Domain Accounts and Change Permissions?

Tags: security, registry

Is there an application to remove the Computer\Administrators group and the Computer\Administrator account and their permissions across the registry and file system and replace them with the Enterprise|Domain\Administrators group after joining a system to a domain?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to add the Domain | Enterprise Administrator groups to the Local Administrators Group, not deleting it.